# how to fix easily this error Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I developed php simple page to register users and check if the user exists or not but it is not working and displays the fallowing error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/one/include/DbOperation.php on line 31

and php code here please help us for this issue

```
<?php
class DbOperation
{
    private $conn;


enter code here
    //Constructor
    function __construct()
    {

        require_once('Constants.php');
        require_once('DbConnect.php');
        // opening db connection
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    //Function to create a new user
    public function createUser($username, $pass, $email, $name, $phone)
    {
        if (!$this->isUserExist($username, $email, $phone)) {
            $password = md5($pass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, name, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $email, $name, $phone);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return USER_CREATED;
            } else {
                return USER_NOT_CREATED;
            }
        } else {
            return USER_ALREADY_EXIST;
        }
    }


    private function isUserExist($username, $email, $phone)
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR phone = ?");
        //if($query = $this->db->conn->prepare($sql)){
        $stmt->bind_param(array("sss", $username, $email, $phone));
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
      return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your isUserExist() function it looks like your `bind_param` has an array which shouldn't be there:

`$stmt->bind_param(array("sss", $username, $email, $phone));`

should be:

`$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $phone);`

This is most likely why `mysqli->bind_param` is returning `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

change your `isUserExist` as below:

```
private function isUserExist($username, $email, $phone)
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR phone = ?");
        //if($query = $this->db->conn->prepare($sql)){
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $phone); // change here remove array
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
        //$stmt->close(); // change this comment or remove this
      return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in `isUserExist()` function

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $phone);
```